# Solve multi properties joining

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's assume that I'm having two tables: PropertyTypes and Properties

```
PropertyTypes 
ID    |     Name
1     |     Color
2     |     Country
3     |     Size

Properties
ID    |  ID PropertyTypes | Name
1     |  1                | Red
2     |  1                | Blue
3     |  1                | Green
4     |  2                | China
5     |  2                | Macau
6     |  3                | S
7     |  3                | L
```

For example, if I choose properties 1,2,4 5 above, if there are 2 distinct PropertyTypes, the list I want looks like (2x2=4):

```
Red-China
Red-Macau
Green-China
Green-Macau
```

If I choose all properties, here are 3 distinct PropertyTypes, the list I want which looks like(3x2x2=12):

```
Red-China-S
Red-Macau-S
Blue-China-S
Blue-Macau-S
Green-China-S
Green-Macau-S
Red-China-L
Red-Macau-L
Blue-China-L
Blue-Macau-L
Green-China-L
Green-Macau-L
```

And so on, if we add more PropertyTypes and Properties in the future

I can't figure out how to do the loop to get those result for future extending without changing the code and avoid duplicating.

Please help me if you figured out something.

Comment: If you have code that works for those three properties, post that as an example and maybe someone will help you make it future-proof :)

Comment: You've got 3 property. combine two of them as you did in the example, and consider it like a single property. Then, you could do all the combination with the third property